# What video editor is capable of slowing the audio while editing?

Tags: windows, video-editing

I want to download a video editor on Windows 10. My videos are somewhat like slideshows (for example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Knf2MpzJMJI)), I put the recitation audio on the program, then I add images and I move the images to make them coincide with the audio, but problem, the [video editor I currently use](http://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-editor/download) doesn't have an option to make the video slower for editing, I want to slow down the audio so I can listen and make the images coincide more accurately with the audio. I also want it to "quickly" insert the image into the program, I mean I don't want inserting the image and then making it coincide with the audio a long process, in [that editor](http://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-editor/download) I just moved the "cursor" and then put the image on the cursor. I'm fine with a low price such as somewhat around or below $15, though I really prefer free. Jazakum Allah khayran.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, how much you're willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions, what other features do you need. Please don't expect people hopping around and chasing links to figure details, instead include the essentials here.

Comment: @Izzy edited it, and really those mentioned in the question are the only features I need. May Allah grant us understanding, I'm only mixing audio with images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to try VideoProc from Digiarity. It has many features along with adjusting audio. Some of the top features are adjusting, resizing, transcoding, and editing. But this costs you approx $30 but definitely worth!